# Phone / Skype Dialing Option

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, settings, calls

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII.GT-I9100 Android Version 4.1.2
Recently I installed their latest upgrade. I still have the option to choose between Phone & Skype when I am dialing, which is great, but now they have a second annoying choice which must be made each time. That is ALWAYS or JUST ONCE which then immediately sets that as the default.
This means there has to be an extra choice pressed each time I want to make a call.
Is there a way to disable that ridiculous feature & still retain the Phone/Skype option.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: So...you want a choice to be presented but you don't want the choice to be presented? I'm a touch confused. In any case, try double-tapping the app of choice to have it open immediately when the choice box shows up.

Comment: Confused, "You want to disable that Always/Just-once option, is that your question?"

Comment: Sparx/MattLin: Easily understood when you encountered it once :) While up to ICS, you had a single popup with the app selection plus a checkbox "always use", with 4.1 you get two popups: 1 to select the app (no checkbox anymore), and a second whether you want to remember that choice. Peter obviously wants to get rid of the second, but keep the first popup; basically the pre-4.1 behavior to be restored. Is that possible?

Comment: Android 4.2.2 (Touchwiz ROM not available yet) updates this functionality by including Always/Just-Once in first popup itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the old popup back, but Sparx's suggestion is correct: if you double-tap the app, it has the same effect as clicking "Just once". Hopefully this is quick and easy enough that the new-style chooser doesn't annoy you any more.